SSL_read: I/O error: Get kicked out back to the the windows RDP client when trying to rdp to an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop
xrdp was installed on Ubuntu 22.04 desktop using
sudo apt install xrdp -y 
sudo systemctl status xrdp 
sudo usermod -a -G ssl-cert xrdp 
sudo systemctl restart xrdp 

And the logs are
[20240423-20:47:04] [ERROR] SSL_read: I/O error
[20240423-20:47:04] [ERROR] libxrdp_force_read: header read error
[20240423-20:47:04] [ERROR] Processing [ITU-T T.125] Connect-Initial failed
[20240423-20:47:04] [ERROR] [MCS Connection Sequence] receive connection request failed
[20240423-20:47:04] [ERROR] xrdp_sec_incoming: xrdp_mcs_incoming failed
[20240423-20:47:04] [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_incoming: xrdp_sec_incoming failed
[20240423-20:47:04] [ERROR] xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed
[20240423-20:47:04] [ERROR] xrdp_iso_send: trans_write_copy_s failed
[20240423-20:47:04] [ERROR] Sending [ITU T.125] DisconnectProviderUltimatum failed

Not sure how to address the above

xrdp user should be added to the relevant group.
sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert


this may not show up to a process until it is restarted

The described installation included sudo usermod -a -G ssl-cert xrdp that implies sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert

The described installation included a restart of xrdp using sudo systemctl restart xrdp
